# Similarities detector for IEEE conference papers like crosscheck

Tags: publications, ieee

IEEE conferences managed thru EDAS system are usually interfaced with Crosscheck service which automatically highlight to reviewers the percentage of detected similarity for the paper to be reviewed with existing papers.

Unfortunately, this service can only be accessed thru the conference admin console.
I checked with IEEE support who confirmed that such service cannot be accessed by an end-user but only activated as a paid service for a conference.

Also, I think, I remember that another API called ithenticate is sometimes used.

My question is:
As an author, not as a reviewer,
How would I know what is the computed resemblance percentage of my paper to existing works prior submission?

Comment: Check with your university libraries or your supervisor. This is a paid application.

Comment: Yes, IEEE support confirmed that this is a paid service and it's only accessible by API thru the conference administration panel.

Comment: Why do you need to check your own paper for plagiarism? You wrote it; don't plagiarize.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I think the OP is not interested in knowing if their paper is plagiarized or not; they are probably interested in what number comes up even if they don't plagiarize.  Would it be 0%? 10%?

Comment: @BrianKrause  We keep getting questions like this because somebody is wrongly teaching students that plagiarism software measures plagiarism.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Then they should ask that question. As is it looks like they think they are going to measure how plagiarized their paper is with software rather than measuring how plagiarized their paper is by knowing it's zero because they didn't plagiarize, or knowing it's unacceptable because they did.

Comment: @BryanKrause  Take an example, someone already has published three or four 12-18 pages journal papers, now if the author decides to write a short and novel idea on a letter-format (3-4 pages), he needs to take the necessary parts from previous papers, obviously with citations. It doesn’t matter how he rewrites the phrase or rewrites in ‘own’ words, these softwares used by many publishers detect a similarity score around 10~20%. It is not plagiarism, but due to the short length and taking some phases from previous papers, these papers enters to plagiarized queue in the editorial process.

Comment: @user199 I am well aware plagiarism software returns false alarms. Which is why there is no point in doing what the OP is asking to do.

Comment: @BryanKrause Totally agreed. It doesn’t make any sense to use these software from the author side, however it is useful for the editors and publishers when the ratio is beyond a threshold. They can check these submissions with their eyes not using bots. Now, if the author knows these in advance (we somehow know which software is being used by publishers, in several occasions, the publishers explicitly mentioned these), he can manipulate these output. It’s a good and bad use of plagiarism checking software.

Comment: You also run into the potential risk that you repeat yourself throughout multiple papers. For instance, you describe the general problem you are tackling with your (series of) papers. Even if you write it from scratch each time and adjust it to the specific paper, this can still be rather "similar".
I think it is no bad idea to have a look at this. If it helps the honest(!) author to sleep better at night, that's just fine.

Comment: Hello Guys, thanks for your inputs. This is not nut or anything. @Bryan, Just put yourself in my shoes, if you are working on a particular problem and you published a first contribution (first finding) (method to tackle your problem with enhancements compared to literature). Now, you evaluate a second approach (comparing yourself and literature). The frame/scope of the problem is the same, the literature is similar. You will plagiarize yourself. Some editors impose 30% max similarities, which is easy topped due to these a/m reasons.

Comment: How would you plagiarize yourself if you are properly citing and documenting your previous work in your new paper? Seems like the detection system is faulty, or OP isn't writing properly.